# Adding TextBox in FORM with AddNew Button

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am working in Oracle Apex .i want to add `TextBox i-e Disease` from AddNew Button because i have Multiple Entries for one `TextBox`.The entries will be selected from another table through `POPUP LOV`. Below is the picture.[image]

Comment: The answer depends on how you will store the extra values for DISEASE: do you want them listed in the one VARCHAR2 field in the treatment table (e.g. `'GOUT:ASPERGERS:PARKINSONS'`) or are they stored in a normalised child table on the database (e.g. `treatment_diseases (treat_id, disease)`?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I want to store the extra table values in the same table i-e treatment table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I can explain it step by step here, but it sounds like you could make use of a Tabular Form in your case.

In a Tabular form, you can dynamically add-update-delete new rows with a button, and for each field you can have Popop LOVS or Comboboxes to select data from.

Here are a few things to note:

- When you insert a Tabular Form in your page, you'll instantly get three processes; one for Automated Row Fetching and two for save-update operations. By default, these processes are triggered through a button. You might want to change that since you have other items to submit in your page.
- In a tabular form, you define a SQL query and the resulting columns of that query becomes your fields. For each field, you can select whether you want it to be a Combobox, Popup LOV etc.

Comment: @ Erkan ...I know that ..But my question is that can we make it in form on Table instead of Tabular Form..

Comment: @Erkan..Can u tell me how should i make the LOV for specific column in Tabular Form

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use a single column "`DISEASE`" in your treatment table, you can use one of the list item types that support multiple values (generally separated by colons (:)) - for example, a Shuttle.